# Is/ are followed by a number

Tags: grammar

Which is correct?

> This month is 8 years since I stopped playing guitar.
>   This month are 8 years since I stopped plating guitar?

Comment: *This month it has been 8 years since I stopped playing guitar.*

Comment: How do you plate a guitar, and why would you do that?

Answer (score 2):

In all these cases, the actual or implied subject of the sentence is **a period of time**, irrespective of whether that *period of time* is one month or ten years. So, given that the subject is **a [single] period of time** - not a [multiple] number of days, months or years - the subject is *normally* singular.

I say 'normally' because there may be constructions where the subject actually becomes plural, although I cannot currently think of one!

I would add that, in many cases, the word "**it**" is included in the sentences and used to refer to the period of time, such as:

> This month, **it** is 8 years since I stopped playing guitar.
>   Next month, **it** will be 8 years since I stopped playing guitar.

The use of "it" is shown in the answer from Bob Bobaloobob and the comment from Peter Shor.

The actual word "it" may be omitted, especially in speech, but it is nevertheless implied as the subject of the sentence.  Thus, normally the verb should be **singular**, not plural.

Answer (score 0):

Both versions seem strange and awkward in English.  I would phrase it differently:  “It has been eight years this month since I played a guitar.” or “I have not played a guitar for eight years, as of this month.”

Comment: Today is ten years since I sold my Caddy; This week is twenty years since my dog Bozo was run down by a truck. Neither strange nor awkward in informal conversation.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That must depend on dialect or location. To me, those are all not just strange and awkward, but completely ungrammatical and nonexistent. It can be difficult in natural speech to tell _it’s_ and _is_ apart, so I may have heard _is_ and automatically interpreted it as _it’s_, but I have definitely not seen it written before, and I don’t recall ever hearing a clear _is_ with no _it_ either.

Comment: Maybe it's a British localism: "Today is ten years since the smoking ban came in"; "Today is ten years since Heath Ledger tragically passed aged only 28."; "Today is ten years since the hashtag was first used,"; "today is ten years since the first episode of Primeval"; "Today is ten years since Twilight was released in UK cinemas"; but not only - "Today is ten years since we all said goodbye to you." - US memorial announcement